# Use Image Gallery as a menu

Tags: android, image, menu, onclick, gallery

I'm trying to use an image gallery for my application menu. The objective is that when the user click on a image it will send you to a particular activity. The problem is that I don´t know how to associate each image with each activity. For example if you click on the first image it opens a game, if you click on the second one you go to the application options... How can I do it?

```
public class Carrusel extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView lastClicked = null;
int padding = 10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.start);
LinearLayout l;
l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.carrusel);
int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5};
for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(images[i]);
    iv.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    iv.setOnClickListener(this);
    l.addView(iv);
}
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i= new Intent (this, Flip3d.class);
    startActivity (i);

}
}
```

The last "onClick" was a test of what I was trying. Obviously in this case all the images open the same activity, that is what I want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Create on OnClickListener for each of your ImageViews.

```
iv.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   OnClick(View v) {
     // start the activity you want
   }
});
```

Comment: I don´t know how can I implement this solution in my code. I have tried but it gives me errors. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can set ids for your imageview which can be used in onClick to identify your view.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(images[i]);
        iv.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        iv.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv.setId(mIvIds[i]);
        l.addView(iv);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == mIvIds[0]) {
        Intent i= new Intent (this, Flip3d.class);
        startActivity (i);
    } else if (v.getId() == mIvIds[1]) {
    // other stuff
    } else if (v.getId() == mIvIds[2]) {
    // ...
    }

}
```

But firstly you need to generate new ids for `mIvIds[]`. In API17 was View.generateViewId() added for this feature. But if only your imageviews are attached to that onclick listener i think there should be no problem if you use some random integers (e.g. 1,2,3,... )